# PHP keep form data after failed submit

Tags: php, forms

I know that there are many similar questions here that has been answered, but none of the answers has worked for me. I simply want the information that the user has already typed in to stay in the fields when the form submission fails (because of empty fields or such). I have tried using the code below but it doesn't work.

register.php:

```html
<form class="form" id="form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
<label>Full name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter full name..." name="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['name']); } ?>">
<button type="submit" id="registerbtn" name="submit" value="submit" >Register</button>
</form>
```

signup.inc.php:

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
  $pwdRepeat = $_POST["pwdrepeat"];
  $phone = $_POST["phone"];
  $address = $_POST["address"];
  $city = $_POST["city"];
  $value = $_POST['usertype'];

  require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
  require_once 'functions.inc.php';

  if (emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $pwd, $pwdRepeat, $phone, $address, $city) !== false) {
    header("location: ../register.php?error=emptyinput");
    exit();
  }
  if (invalidEmail($email) !== false) {
    header("location: ../register.php?error=invalidemail");
    exit();
  }
  if (emailExists($conn, $email) !== false) {
    header("location: ../register.php?error=emailtaken");
    exit();
  }
  if (pwdMatch($pwd, $pwdRepeat) !== false) {
    header("location: ../register.php?error=passwordsdontmatch");
    exit();
  }
  if (pwdLength($pwd) !== false) {
    header("location: ../register.php?error=passwordistooshort");
    exit();
  }
  if (cityUpperCase($city) !== false) {
    header("location: ../register.php?error=cityhasnouppercase");
    exit();
  }

  createUser($conn, $name, $email, $pwd, $phone, $address, $city, $value);

} else {
  header("location: ../register.php");
  exit();
}
```

I also have a functions.inc.php containing the called functions in signup.inc.php.

Comment: Because you redirect user to different page.

Comment: You can use AJAX for this

Comment: Or use persistent storage like sessions

Comment: Your Location header redirect causes the browser to make a _GET_ request for the specified URL, so no _POST_ parameters will exists at all then when the script runs. Apart from what was already suggested, another common approach is to have the form generation, _and_ the processing of the submitted data, in the same script. Then when validation fails, you can output the form directly from there again, where the POST parameters still exist.

Comment: In the form most of the fields are missing? Is this intentional?      Most simple solution: combine the two page to just one - then you will have the values available after POST.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev how do I do this?

Comment: put your HTML form and signup.inc.php file content in the same file and set form `action=''`

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig the fields are there in my code, I just skipped the rest of them here to save some space. My bad, should've probably mentioned that!

Comment: The page stops working when I put the file contents in the same file... :/

Answer (score 0):

Here i have made a VERY SIMPLE outline how to do this  and some sample code (not tested and posibly full of typos..   its just the concept no working code

Show the form if nothing is submitted or an error happens.

IT IS NOT user friendly to only display one error at a time  - show all arrors so the user can fix them all at a time (your former script only sjowed one error before redirect
so collect all errors in one string array objecht - what you like  and display them  together.

ask if there have been any error and if not and if all checks wer ok then do the insert
or show the error(s)

check the insert

if  nothing has been submitted or an error occured show the form.

echo the sumbitted values into the form - probably better to sanitize the values and not put the $_POST values into it  eg by

(NULL COALESCING OPERATOR  ?? if  the value before ?? is NULL then use '' othersise the value before the ?? )
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm

```
  <?php
    
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    
      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $email = $_POST["email"];
      $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
      $pwdRepeat = $_POST["pwdrepeat"];
      $phone = $_POST["phone"];
      $address = $_POST["address"];
      $city = $_POST["city"];
      $value = $_POST['usertype'];
    
      require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
      require_once 'functions.inc.php';
    
    error="";
    
      if (emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $pwd, $pwdRepeat, $phone, $address, $city) !== false) {
        $error .= $emptyinput."<br>";
        ;
      }
      if (invalidEmail($email) !== false) {
         $error .= $invalidemail."<br>";
             }
      }
[all other sanitations  and checks ]

    
    if (empty($error))
{ $result=createUser($conn, $name, $email, $pwd, $phone, $address, $city, $value);
 }
else{
echo $error; 
}   
 
if ($result==TRUE)  
{
exit(); // to prevent the display of the form // or do if condition below. 
}

   } 



    ?>
    
    <!--  other HTML necessary code  -->
    
    <form class="form" id="form" action="" method="post">
    <label>Full name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter full name..." name="name" value="<?= $_POST['name']??'';?>">
    
    [... all the other fields....   ]

    <button type="submit" id="registerbtn" name="submit" value="submit" >Register</button>
    </form>
    
 <!--  other HTML necessary code  -->
    }
```